# Splunk : TCP Port Data Input not appearing in Search Data Sources

Tags: tcp, udp, logging, splunk

So the problem comes down to -

1. Redirecting the output of my `$ python script.py` to a TCP Port using nc.
2. Capturing the data remotely listening to the Port.
3. Now when I remotely listen this port number's stream using nc, the data is being redirected properly.
4. When I add to Data Inputs to listen to the port in Splunk, I don't get any data(there is not syslog or logs from tornado).
5. Also, there is nothing added to the data sources when I hit search tab in Splunk (all visual).
6. When I use a file and redirect the port output to this file using nc and then use that file as a source for Splunk it works perfectly.

Now as per point 6, I would have get my results by redundantly storing my log in a temp file and Splunk which is not desired. And as per point 4, my data is not showing up directly when Splunk listens to my TCP port.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was - When the port number is being listened by nc itself on the splunk computer, it wasn't coming as a data source in splunk itself. Which certainly makes sense as the data would be lost to nc before it reaches splunk.

This shows a loophole in splunk which could be corrected. They do point out busy ports but they should also point our multiple listeners at that port.

My question's closed.